# How to SSH into virt-manager guest from host?

Tags: ssh, virtualization, linux-kvm, virt-manager, virtual-network

I have a Debian host OS. I installed `virt-manager` and created a guest Ubuntu 22.04 OS on a virtual machine.

I retrieved the IP address of the guest OS by running `ip addr` on the (Ubuntu) guest OS's terminal. Let's say it is `192.168.1.10`.

Now, from on the host (Debian) terminal, I execute

`ssh username@192.168.1.10`

but it halts and then times out.

Why? And what is the minimum that I need to do to make this work? I also installed openssh-server and made sure to unblock the firewall on port 22 on the guest OS.

Comment: Things to check: (1) Is there an SSH server running in the guest OS? (2) Does the firewall in the guest allow connections to the SSH server?

Comment: Yes, running `sudo systemctl status ssh` on the guest shows that port 22 is listening. And I did run on the guest `sudo ufw allow 22` to remove the firewall from that port.

Comment: Have you tried to ping the host system from your guest? If yes, what has happened? Also, how have you established the guest's network connectivity?